# Obtaining text output via QTP

Tags: telnet, qtp, text-extraction

I am using QTP to open a telnet window to router, where I am logging into the router and giving some router specific commands. I am doing as follows,

```
JavaWindow("myApp").JavaButton("telnetBtn").Click
JavaWindow("myApp").JavaEdit("textAreaWindow").Type "admin"
JavaWindow("myApp").JavaEdit("textAreaWindow").Type micReturn
wait 3
JavaWindow("myApp").JavaEdit("textAreaWindow").Type "lab"
JavaWindow("myApp").JavaEdit("textAreaWindow").Type micReturn
wait 3
JavaWindow("myApp").JavaEdit("textAreaWindow").Type "show version"
JavaWindow("myApp").JavaEdit("textAreaWindow").Type micReturn
```

With this code, I am able to give commands. After this, I need to get the output from this command which is being displayed in the `'textAreaWindow'`.

At least, Is it possible to get all the text being displayed in the JavaEdit object ?

How I can get this ?

Comment: So you decided to not look at the documentation: Look f.e. at the getROProperty method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the value of the `JavaEdit` should be in available via it's `value` property. If you use the object spy on the control does the `value` contain the requested value?

If so you can access it using `GetROProperty`

```
MsgBox JavaWindow("myApp").JavaEdit("textAreaWindow").GetROProperty("value")
```

If this is not the value you want you can examine the underlying Java object via the `.Object` property

```
JavaWindow("myApp").JavaEdit("textAreaWindow").Object
```